# Outlook 2013 How to create a new e-mail and default its position

Tags: email, outlook, office-2013

Whenever I create a new e-mail (new message, forward, reply, reply-all, etc.) I want to have it open up in a specific position relevant to my monitor.

If you push the windows key + right arrow button it aligns the selected application to cover the right half of the monitor (windows key + left arrow aligns it with left half of monitor).  I want the new e-mail to open up in this position.

But upon a new e-mail prompting it is just a random size that covers a percentage of the screen.

Tried to look online and through Stack Exchange but this could be one of those "too much efficiency problems" my friends tell me I have.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use Inspector.Left/Top/Width/Height properties to set the inspector position.

Inspector object can be retrieved from MailItem.GetInspector, Application.ActiveInspector, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, so it does have to be done through dev.  Thanks for the response, this may have to be something I experiment with further down the road.